# How to link a shared library (.so) to a CUDA source file (.cu) using nvcc?

Tags: c++, c, cuda

Currently, I'm compiling my CUDA source file using:

```
nvcc -O3 --shared -Xcompiler -fPIC -o CuFile.so CuFile.cu
```

I'd like to call functions from a shared library called `GlobalFunctions.so`.

**How can I link the library to the CUDA source file?**

So far, I've tried

```
nvcc -O3 --shared -Xcompiler -fPIC -lGlobalFunctions -o CuFile.so CuFile.cu
```

and a few variants, but nothing worked.

Comment: Could you perhaps expand on what "nothing worked" means? Did you get an error message you could share with us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems evident to me that you are making some mistakes in library naming/usage/referencing, but since you don't show any actual output, I'll just make a suggestion.  The changes below should make evident some of the errors (e.g. not preceding library name with `lib`, not specifying `-L.` or similar, etc.)  I suspect none of this is unique or specific to CUDA/`nvcc`, as the behavior and command syntax with e.g. `g++` should be more or less the same.

The following is one possible approach:

```
$ cat foo.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"
void foo(){
  printf("Hello from foo\n");
}
$ cat foo.h
void foo();
$ cat CuFile.cu
#include "foo.h"
#include "CuFile.h"

void bar(){

  foo();
}
$ cat CuFile.h
void bar();
$ cat test.cu
#include "CuFile.h"

int main(){

  bar();
}
$ nvcc -O3 --shared -Xcompiler -fPIC -o libGlobalFunctions.so foo.cu
$ nvcc -O3 --shared -Xcompiler -fPIC  CuFile.cu -L. -lGlobalFunctions -o libCuFile.so
$ nvcc -O3 test.cu -o test -L. -lCuFile
$ ./test
Hello from foo
$
```

If your intermediate library is actually called `GlobalFunctions.so` and not `libGlobalFunctions.so` (and you don't wish to rename it) then one possible approach is just to pass it directly:

```
$ nvcc -O3 --shared -Xcompiler -fPIC CuFile.cu GlobalFunctions.so -o libCuFile.so
```

The `-l` switch for `g++` and `nvcc` when specified like this: `-lxyz` will look for a library by the name of `libxyz.so` or `libxyz.a`.  So if your library name doesn't begin with `lib`, then I don't know how to use the `-l` switch to reference it (perhaps there is a way).  Also, when you have a library that is in the current directory, and you attempt to refer to that library with `-l` you must also use `-L.` to tell the linker to look there for that library.  The linker doesn't automatically search the current directory for referenced libraries.

Again, I think all of this applies equally to `g++`, so if you can figure out how to do it with `g++` you can probably figure out how to do it with `nvcc`.